# Azure Application Insights - Summarize by part of timestamp

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

How can I summarize records by year, month,day and hour only?

Comment: Are you using [Application Insights Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics)? If so, try [datepart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#datepart)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In Application Insights Analytics:

By hour:

```
requests 
 | summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1h)
```

By day:

```
requests 
 | summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1d)
```

By month

```
requests 
  | summarize count()  by bin(datepart("Month", timestamp), 1)
```

By year

```
requests 
  | summarize count()  by bin(datepart("Year", timestamp), 1)
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that there are also aliases for this: startofday(timestamp), startofweek, startofmonth and startofyear. it should be a bit easier to use.